What are the options for calling another instance's parent class method? And any pros or cons?
I have a setup something like this:


class Parent {
  constructor(id){
    this.id = id;
    this.partner = null;
  }
  fn(x) {
    console.log(`Parent:${this.id}:fn(${x})`);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(id){
    super(id);
  }
  fn(x) {
    console.log(`Child:${this.id}:fn(${x})`);
    super.fn(x);
    console.log('  -> calling partner');
    // Trigger partner too (**** this is key line I'm asking about) 
    Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this.partner)).fn.call(this.partner, x);
  }
  setPartner(partner){
    this.partner = partner;
  }
}

a = new Child('a');
b = new Child('b');

a.setPartner(b);
b.setPartner(a);

a.fn('test a');
console.log('');
b.fn('test b');



So I've got one class instance calling a function in another class instance, and to avoid infinite loops I call the parent method.
My question is whether there are any other sensible ways to call another instances parent function?
In writing this question, I've realised that it's probably cleaner to create _fn(x) as below to solve the underlying problem, but I'm still interested in understanding the possible approaches to the calling a parent class method.
I originally thought I could call proto.proto but that didn't work when I tried to use it in a snippet. I wondered if there was some way to use super to do it super.fn.call(this, x) or similar


class Parent {
  constructor(id){
    this.id = id;
    this.partner = null;
  }
  fn(x) {
    console.log(`Parent:${this.id}:fn(${x})`);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(id){
    super(id);
  }
  _fn(x) {
      console.log(`Child:${this.id}:fn(${x})`);
      super.fn(x);
  }
  fn(x) {
      this._fn(x);
      console.log('   calling partner ->');
      this.partner._fn.call(this.partner, x);
  }
  setPartner(partner){
    this.partner = partner;
  }
}

a = new Child('a');
b = new Child('b');

a.setPartner(b);
b.setPartner(a);

a.fn('test a');
console.log('');
b.fn('test b');




Seems like there's a problem with your object model(s) if you feel the need to call a parent method from the outside.

In other words, this is breaking encapsulation a lot. Within a class, you can make safe assumptions about inheritance and calling parents. But for other objects, you should not reach that deep into the object, as that's coupling very tightly to implementation details.

That said, you can provide a facility on the parent class called "fna", and then give the inheriting class an "fnb" that uses the parent method to provide additional functionality. Still seems a little sus, but I can see how that might make sense in some cases.

super.fn.call(this.partner, x) should indeed work, have you tried it? Never use Object.getPrototypeOf(…).fn.call(…), as that breaks down completely (leading to infinite recursion again) if your method is called on another subclass and not a Child.

My own conclusions writing this question, confirmed by the comments, are this approach is to be avoided as its fragile, and I'm using the second approach outlined in my question.
However to answer the question as asked (thanks @bergi), I would use:
super.fn.call(this.partner, x)

To call the partner parent function.
